# onLoad() jQuery not working correctly because of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hps' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My onLoad jQuery function is not working. The HTML starts with a "loading" gif, and the jQuery should fade in the `featured-photo` while fading out `image-loader`.

The `loadImage` function is called in the html, and causes an error because `window.app` is undefined in the HTML.  Like this:

**html**

```
 <div class="featured-photo">
      <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" class="lazy-image" onload="window.app.hps.loadImage(this, '.featured-photo')"/>
 </div>
```

**application.js**

```
    loadImage: function(img, attachment_class)
    { 
            var backgroundImage = $(img).attr('src');
                console.log("Lazy load image: "+backgroundImage);

                $('.image-loader').fadeOut();
                $('.post-loaders').fadeIn();
                $(attachment_class).css("opacity", 0).css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')').css("opacity", 1);
    }
```

The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hps' of undefined`, which I understand means `window.app` is undefined in the html page.  My question is how do I properly define `window.app` within the html so the function will work?

The function is defined in `application.js` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    window.app = new Application({ el: $("body") });
    if ( $('body').hasClass("page-id-142") ) { revenew(); }
});
```

But I'm not sure how to define it in the HTML properly.

Comment: I wonder if the `img` `onload` fires before the `document ready`.  Try adding a couple of console messages in their handles to make sure.  Can you put your logic in the `document` event?

Comment: @Branco I would definitely be open to that but I'm really new to jQuery and not sure what that would look like.  Having trouble figuring out how to put console messages in too, the things I'm searching just turn up how to open the JS console

Comment: `Console.log("your text message here");`

Comment: that gave me more errors about Console being undefined, not sure.  Is there a way to just define window.app in html? putting the `loadImage` function in the `document` didn't help

Comment: My bad... lowercase.. `console.log()`...  And what do you mean in the HTML?  The `onload` event invokes a JS call so it goes to your page's JS scope.  The problem looks to be a difference in which part loads first.  The html looks to fire the `onload` before the document fires the `ready` event.

Comment: @Branco ok.  the console went like this: 1. Uncaught exception on window.app undefined 2. application init 3. homepage init 4. ready console message.  The imageLoad didn't fire a message.  I thought the `onload`should happen after `onready`, and the error message comes, but since the console message didn't fire I'm not sure what happened

Comment: What I meant was to fire custom logic on each event and forget about the `window.app` part.  Basically, you set each of them to define themselves in the console.  E.g., `console.log("some event firing");` in an event handler so you can see the load order of things.

Comment: From what I can tell `onLoad` and `ready` aren't compatible and I need to rewrite the script to work within the `ready` function that has my window.app defined above.  If anyone could provide an answer on how to do this properly I'd appreciate it, I'm working on it but I'm bad at free-forming JS syntax